# How to count items of nested lists?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I use the Stream API to count items of nested lists?

Imagine 3 nested lists:

```
List<OuterList> outerLists;

class OuterList {
    List<Sublist> subLists;
}

class Sublist {
    List<String> items;
}
```

I just want to sum the number of `items.size()` of all lists. I'm trying to achive something like:

```
outerLists.stream().forEach(outer -> 
  outer.getSubLists().stream().forEach(sub -> 
  sub.getItems().size())
 .sum/count()?
```

Comment: Whatever you want to do with a stream, `forEach` is not the right tool for the job in 99% of all cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-):

```
outerLists.stream()
          .flatMapToInt(outer ->
              outer.subLists.stream().mapToInt(sub -> sub.items.size())
          )
          .sum();
```

This will be more performant than flat mapping the whole sublists since here, we're just mapping each sublist into the size of its items. The idea here is that the `Stream<OuterList>` is flat mapped into an `IntStream` where each outer is replaced to a stream made of the size of all its inner lists. Then, we sum the values with [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flatMap` to convert a `Stream<OuterList>` to a `Stream<Sublist>` and then to a `Stream<String>` of all the `String`s in all the innermost lists :

```
outerLists.stream()
          .flatMap(ol -> ol.subLists().stream())
          .flatMap(s->s.items.stream()).count();
```

However, if there are duplicates, they will be counted multiple times.